# asp.net web forms -- 404 on publish

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, publish

I'm having some issues getting my project to publish to a server for work.
we don't have a folder shared to the project directory or a FTP server setup so in order to publish I have to publish it locally, remote into the server, then copy/paste the project files into the desired location.

I have done this plenty of times before with no issues but for some reason it is not working for me now. Every time i go to the site I get a HTTP 404

One weird thing that I noticed is in IIS when i click on 'basic settings' the virtual path is set as /portalDEV/Apps, alias is UA, and physical path is D:\websites\portalDEV\Apps\UA, When i click on 'test settings' i get an error saying invalid application path.

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 0):

On your server IIS you must create virtual path who link physical path of your application.

1. You set an alias
2. You set the directory of your application
3. In the end of treatment your check the framework version section

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the issue when i click on the application all of the folders and files appear correctly proving that the application's virtual directory is pointing to the right spot. see below:

http://imageshack.us/a/img849/4140/screensv.jpg

Comment: so ensure that you had added all your files to your deployment